# Fragment Calling in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

[image][image]I have following  contain in project

1> Fragment activity with Action Bar (Home Fragment)

2> Tab Fragment

2.1> Tab 1 Fragment

2.2> Tab 2 Fragment

3> Other Fragment

In Fragment Activity, call Tab Fragment it shows 2 tab in that when fragment activity loading initially.

Tab 1 Fragment have some fields with button

Tab 2 Fragment have some fields with button

When I click on Tab 1 Fragment button, I want to show

> > > Other Fragment in `FrameLayout` which is present in main xml
> > >
> > > Hide `TabFragment` Totally with Tab 1 and Tab 2 Fragment which is present in Tab Fragment

```
        android:id="@+id/mainframlayout"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:layout_height="0dip"

        android:layout_weight="1" />
```

when i write this code in Tab1 Fragment on click Button it remove the Tab1 Fragment

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(this).commit();
```

But I want to remove total Tab Fragment and load Other Fragment In that Frame Layout Please help me for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the reference of `TabFragment` to `Tab1Fragment` and call remove fragment for it.

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(parentFragment).commit();
```

You can do this while creating new instance of tab 1 fragment just pass TabFragment reference.

onCreateView of flight fragment where you are creating your OneWay, TwoWay fragments:

```
OneWayFragment oneWay=new OneWayFragment();
oneWay.setFlightFragment(FlightFragment.this);
```

In OneWayFragment:

```
class OneWayFragment extends Fragment {
    FlightFragment f;
    public void setFlightFragment(FlightFragment f){
    this.f=f;
    }

    //onClick of button
     Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(),FlightLoadingFragmentActivity.class); 
     getActivity().startActivity(intent);

}
```

**EDIT**

```
class OneWayFragment extends Fragment {
    //onClick of button
     Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(),FlightLoadingFragmentActivity.class); 
     getActivity().startActivity(intent);

}
```

You can create a new activity called FlightLoadingFragmentActivity and in just put the fragment in it's layout